# How to append dynamic dictionary instead of mutate in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dictionary

i have a dictionary with `{75:{}, 76:{}}` and I want to add values based on their id so having `{parent_id: 75, val: 108}, {parent_id: 75, val: 178}` I would get `{75: {108, 178}}`. Instead what i am getting is the value getting overwritten by the latest val.

This is code I am trying

```
for(var item in response.data.data){
       value = response.data.data[item];
       Vue.set(reviewdata, value.parent_id, {value.val});
    }
```

My data looks like `response.data.data = [{parent_id: 75, value: 108}, {parent_id: 7, value: 178}, {parent_id: 76, value: 92}, {parent_id: 76, value: 117}]`

Comment: please detail more your example

Comment: It's not clear what its your data and what do you want ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim added the data

Comment: it's hard to guess how your script is organized and what you want